# sql Query for multiple column condition based on single column condition

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get all the duplicated rows based on a certain conditions in a table.
I'm unable to get it. Here is a look at the table.

## Table:

| MasterId | TaskId | PostType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 | movies |
| 1 | t1 | music |
| 2 | t2 | movies |
| 2 | t2 | movies |
| 2 | t2 | movies |
| 3 | t3 | news |
| 4 | t4 | movies |

MasterId has multiple TaskIds and tasksId's will have multiple 'PostType'.

I 'm trying to get  masterId's that have PostType only 'movies' and not 'news' or 'music'.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation logic next to HAVING clause after GROUPing BY `MasterId` column such as

```sql
SELECT MasterId
  FROM t
 GROUP BY MasterId   
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN PostType = 'movies' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=154df997e3920d066dd245533ed6048a)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. this worked.

Answer (score 0):

seems like an normal selection clausule that you're looking for.

try this

```
select 
    t1.MasterId, 
    t1.TaskId 
from dbo.Table t1
where t1.PostType = 'movies'
and t1.MasterId not in (
    select t2.MasterId 
    from dbo.Table t2 
    where t2.MasterId = t1.MasterId
    and t2.PostType <> 'movies'
)
```